# How to access command line api method if same variable exist in window object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a problem using `copy` method from chrome command line api. Some external tool used in my project is declaring it's own `copy` method.

<s>`copy` keyword typed in console is referencing to `window.copy` instead of global one.</s>

Edit: copy method is overwritten with `var copy = ...` so it has descriptor configurable set to false. I can't remove it to restore original method.

Is there an any way to access console api `copy` method in that specific case?

Comment: Isn't `window` in browsers the global scope?

Comment: Actually it is, but external tool uses `var copy = ...` so it has `configurable` set to `false`. That's why i can't just use `delete window.copy` to restore original one.

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution ?